# sharing a post on facebook with post_id

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

i am having an web application, we are posting a video on Facebook. and a share button on web page for share the video again from web page.
now i have to do is to sync the share count. i was trying if we can find a way to share a post with the post_id and page_id. when the URL get share the share count does not update.

or any idea, hint.

Answer (score 1):

These are two separate "things"/objects in the Facebook Graph as you currently seem to use them. I highly doubt that there's a way to sync this. The Post is a Post, and the web page you're showing the Video is a URL.

Have a look at the following FQLs:

Post: `select post_id, share_info from stream where post_id="{post_id}"`

URL:  `select url, share_count from link_stat where url="{your_url}"`

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/link_stat/

I think it should work if you use OpenGraph objects:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-objects
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/maximizing-distribution-media-content
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/web/share#sharelinks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to try a sort of hack. pic the last half of the ajax URL under the post. and passed the parameters to the Facebook sharer

https://www.facebook.com/ajax/sharer/?s=99&appid=2309869772&p%5B0%5D=100005537284043&p%5B1%5D=230045237190051&share_source_type=unknown

URL_PART2: s=99&appid=2309869772&p%5B0%5D=100005537284043&p%5B1%5D=230045237190051&share_source_type=unknown

https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fstaging.littlecast.com%2Fshopconnect-upload%2F6739f117-3133-4842-bd91-81c888bbaf7c%2Fwall_post

URL_PART1:  https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php

FINAL URL = URL_PART1 + URL_PART2

https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.phps=99&appid=2309869772&p%5B0%5D=100005537284043&p%5B1%5D=230045237190051&share_source_type=unknown

if we share this, the post gets shared from the post ID and the share count gets updated for the original post.